# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I have this stored procedure for Oracle:

```
create or replace
procedure bns_saa_message_get()  <--- PROBLEM IS HERE BC I HAVE NO PARAMS TO PASS
AS
begin
  select HostNumber, SAAMessage from BNS_SAA_MESSAGES where HostNumber=(select max(HostNumber) from BNS_SAA_MESSAGES);
end;
```

I get the following error when I try to compile it:

> ```
> Error(2,31): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:     <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    current
> ```

**Question:**
How do I make a stored procedure where I don't need to pass any arguments to it?

Comment: The Oracle documentation is comprehensive, online and free.  You should really learn ho wto use it to answer trivial syntax questions for yourself.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_procedure.htm#i2072424

Comment: @APC we all have our foibles, and mine is SQL; it just doesn't stick... or maybe I'm just dumb. BTW that's an awesome link!! good find

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the brackets:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE bns_saa_message_get
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT hostnumber, saamessage
     FROM bns_saa_messages
    WHERE hostnumber = (SELECT MAX (hostnumber) FROM bns_saa_messages);
END;
```

EDIT:

To answer your second question...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE bns_saa_message_get
AS
   v_hostnumber bns_saa_messages.hostnumber%TYPE;
   v_saamessage bns_saa_messages.saamessage%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT hostnumber, saamessage
     INTO v_hostnumber, v_saamessage 
     FROM bns_saa_messages
    WHERE hostnumber = (SELECT MAX (hostnumber) FROM bns_saa_messages);
END;
```

This assumes you only get one row returned from your query....
If you get more than one row then you'll have to [bulk collect](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_bulk_collect.htm) into a collection.

Comment: If I omit () I get another error: `Error(4,4): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement`

Comment: That's a completely separate issue, Adrian. It has nothing to do with the question you've asked here.

Comment: @RobKennedy I know I wanted to see if I could ask another question :P Tx

Comment: Of course, Adrian. You're always welcome to [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). It'll probably have something to do with how to [return the results of a select statement from a procedure to the caller](https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle%20return%20results%20of%20select%20from%20procedure%20to%20caller).

Comment: You shouldn't really ask follow-on questions but as it is pretty straightforward i have edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Simply omit the parentheses entirely:

```
create or replace
procedure bns_saa_message_get
AS
```

The [railroad diagram in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6009.htm) shows that if you include the opening parenthesis, then at least one argument is required.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the () when you don't have any parameters.

Example: procedure bns_saa_message_get() -> procedure bns_saa_message_get AS